# Código equivalente para funcionar no PHP5.3

Tags: php-7, php-5

Estou utilizando um framework que funciona perfeitamente em um servidor PHP 7.

Mas estou precisando enviar para um servidor PHP 5.3 e algumas funções não estão funcionando.

Confira o código abaixo:

```
<?php

namespace League\Flysystem;

use InvalidArgumentException;
use League\Flysystem\Adapter\CanOverwriteFiles;
use League\Flysystem\Plugin\PluggableTrait;
use League\Flysystem\Util\ContentListingFormatter;

/**
 * @method array getWithMetadata(string $path, array $metadata)
 * @method bool  forceCopy(string $path, string $newpath)
 * @method bool  forceRename(string $path, string $newpath)
 * @method array listFiles(string $path = '', boolean $recursive = false)
 * @method array listPaths(string $path = '', boolean $recursive = false)
 * @method array listWith(array $keys = [], $directory = '', $recursive = false)
 */
class Filesystem implements FilesystemInterface
{
    use PluggableTrait;
    use ConfigAwareTrait;
```

está dando erro nessas duas linhas:

```
use PluggableTrait;
use ConfigAwareTrait;
```

o erro é esse:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE, expecting T_FUNCTION
```

Como posso fazer funcionar o código na versao do PHP 5.3. Tem algum código equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nessas duas linhas destacadas você está aplicando um conceito chamado `trait`, pode ler mais sobre ele [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php). Como ele foi introduzido na versão 5.4 do PHP, é esperado que não funcione na versão 5.3. Considerando que ambas traits são fornecidas por `league/flysystem`, acredito que não seja possível tê-las funcionando com PHP 5.3; principalmente porque, mesmo que você reestruture as traits utilizando de um conceito diferente (e compatível), o código de terceiro deve utilizar de outros recursos também incompatíveis com a versão que está executado.

Você deve considerar atualizar a versão do PHP que está utilizando: [PHP Supported Versions](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).